# How i can use one model for two(or more) different views in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have model that represent `QMap<QString, QVariant>` (list of object attributes) and `QVector<CAttribute>` that represent list of possible attributes. In one `QTableView` I view list of objects with attributes, that i can edit, in second `QTableView` I view list of possible attributes, that i can edit(add more attributes, change it type). Now i have two models based on `QAbstractTableModel` for two tables, but it can't refresh each other. So... i think that there is the way to unite them in one model(maby with proxies?) but i can't find this way. It's my first Qt application(before I learned it only in theory).

Comment: You can try to create one single model and use this model in 2 views, but with hidden columns. In this case 2 view will show changes in model. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: I thought about it... this solution looks like emmmm... fifth leg for dog. And what about absolute different count of rows? I tried to find good solution - it is not production, so i can wait.

Comment: I made sinal/slot mechanism to update each other.

Comment: So, my solution is to use tree model, where one branch is attributes and other is objects.